# Using TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID with Django 1.8

Tags: django

I'm getting following warning when using Django 1.8:

> ?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in
>   Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put
>   the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict:
>   TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID.

I'm using settings from Django 1.7. Where should the `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` go exactly in Django 1.8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = 'Invalid: %s'` or similar from the settings and add `string_if_invalid` to the options of the new `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'string_if_invalid': 'Invalid: "%s"'
        },
    },
]
```

Alternatively if you're using a production and a development settings file, add following statement to the development settings file:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['debug'] = DEBUG
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['context_processors'].append('django.template.context_processors.debug')
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['string_if_invalid'] = 'Invalid: "%s"'
```